# Can we able to add two base adapter in single listview in android?

Tags: android, xml, listview, checkbox, baseadapter

Is it possible to add two adapters in single listview? actually my requirement is set two different adapters to single listview, Adapter1 having ImageView,TextView,Button and Adapter2 having ImageView,TextView,Checkbox, currently i am achieving this task by using two listview in single page, but i am not satisfy with this solution, i searched on google for lots of time, but i didn't get any best solution, i tried merge adapter by cwac-merge-master but things still not achievable, please help me if anyone done merging of two adapters. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have to show both kind of list at same time ?

if yes, you can put your both views in single layout and make them visible or gone based on scenerio which one you have to display ?

Comment: You can use `MergeAdapter` https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge/blob/master/merge/src/com/commonsware/cwac/merge/MergeAdapter.java

Comment: I want to show two types of contact, one is from Phonebook, and another is of application contact,for application contact i am using adapter2(ImageView,TextView,Checkbox), and for phonebook (Adapter1 having ImageView,TextView,Button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check this solution :http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296
it uses the function `getViewTypeCount()` 
for multiply views display

Comment: Thanks for reply, will try with getViewTypeCount()